# How do I obtain a nodes IP address in a swarm using docker remote API?

Tags: docker, containers

How do i obtain a nodes ip address which is part of my swarm. `Docker node inspect` doesn't show ipaddress on both command line or when using the remote API.

Answer (score 0):

You can get hostname from:

```
docker node inspect manager1
"Description": {
            "Hostname": "manager1",
```

Use following to get the value only:

```
docker node inspect --format '{{ .Description.Hostname }}' manager1
manager1
```

I'm sure you are running `DNS` in your environment so it's a matter of dig.

If the node is a manager you can get it's IP:

```
docker node inspect manager1
 "ManagerStatus": {
            "Reachability": "reachable",
            "Addr": "172.30.135.101:2377"
        }
```

Use following to get the value only:

```
docker node inspect --format '{{ .ManagerStatus.Addr }}' manager1
172.30.135.100:2377
```

Comment: Im trying to get a list of IP addresses of nodes on my cluster using the docker remote API